# case in view oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view, case

I have the following view

```
CREATE or replace force VIEW "najme"."VW_CHARGE_REPORT6" ("THRD_PRT_CODE", "RECEIVED_DT", "AUTH_AMT", "APPPAN", "TERMINALID", "TERMINALTYPE_CODE", "SRC_TRNSEQCNTR", "CARDSERIALNO")
AS
  SELECT THRD_PRT_CODE,
    RECEIVED_DT,
    AUTH_AMT,
    APPPAN,
    TERMINALID,
    TERMINALTYPE_CODE,
    SRC_TRNSEQCNTR,
   CARDSERIALNO
  FROM
    (SELECT n.thrd_prt_code,
      i.received_dt,
      rq.auth_amt,
      rq.apppan,
      n.terminalid,
      n.terminaltype_code,
      n.src_trnseqcntr,
      charge.cardserialno
    FROM najme.ifx i
    LEFT JOIN najme.ifx_emv_rq_data rq
    ON rq.id = i.emvrqdata
    LEFT JOIN najme.ifx_emv_rs_data rs
    ON rs.id = i.emvrsdata
    LEFT JOIN najme.IFX_CELL_CHARGE_DATA cell1
    ON cell1.id = i.charge
    LEFT JOIN najme.IFX_CELL_CHARGE_DATA_CHARGES cell
    ON cell.IFX_DATA = cell1.id
    LEFT JOIN najme.ifx_network_trn_info n
    ON i.nettrninfo = n.id
    LEFT JOIN najme.mtn_charge charge
    ON charge.cardserialno = cell.charge
    LEFT JOIN najme.trx_transaxion t
    ON i.trx = t.id
    LEFT JOIN najme.trx_flg_clearing sc
    ON sc.id                 = t.src_clr_flg
    WHERE i.ifx_type        IN (120, 281)
    AND i.trntype            = 19
    AND i.request            = 0
    AND i.direction          = 1
    AND rs.rscode            = '00'
    AND sc.clr_state        IN (1, 2)
    AND charge.cardserialno IS NOT NULL
    AND i.dummycol          IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
```

and I need to show `CARDSERIALNO` with the specified length.I changed the view as seen in follow

```
CREATE or replace force VIEW "najme"."VW_CHARGE_REPORT6" ("THRD_PRT_CODE", "RECEIVED_DT", "AUTH_AMT", "APPPAN", "TERMINALID", "TERMINALTYPE_CODE", "SRC_TRNSEQCNTR", "CARDSERIALNO")
AS
  SELECT THRD_PRT_CODE,
    RECEIVED_DT,
    AUTH_AMT,
    APPPAN,
    TERMINALID,
    TERMINALTYPE_CODE,
    SRC_TRNSEQCNTR,
    (
    CASE
      WHEN charge.COMPANY  IN (9912,9913)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 8    THEN '000000000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (9912,9913)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 9
      THEN '00000000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (9912,9913)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 10
      THEN '0000000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (9912,9913)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 11
      THEN '000000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (9912,9913)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 12
      THEN '00000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (9912,9913)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 13
      THEN '0000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (9912,9913)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 14
      THEN '000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (9912,9913)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 15
      THEN '00'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (9912,9913)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 16
      THEN '0'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (8936,9935,9936,9937)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 11
      THEN '0'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (8936,9935,9936,9937)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 10
      THEN '00'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (8936,9935,9936,9937)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 9
      THEN '000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (8936,9935,9936,9937)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 8
      THEN '0000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (8936,9935,9936,9937)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 7
      THEN '00000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY            IN (8936,9935,9936,9937)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 6
      THEN '000000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      WHEN COMPANY  IN (8936,9935,9936,9937)
      AND LENGTH(CardSerialNo) = 5
      THEN '0000000'
        || TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
      ELSE TO_CHAR(CARDSERIALNO)
    END) AS CARDSERIALNO
  FROM
    (SELECT n.thrd_prt_code,
      i.received_dt,
      rq.auth_amt,
      rq.apppan,
      n.terminalid,
      n.terminaltype_code,
      n.src_trnseqcntr,
      charge.cardserialno
    FROM najme.ifx i
    LEFT JOIN najme.ifx_emv_rq_data rq
    ON rq.id = i.emvrqdata
    LEFT JOIN najme.ifx_emv_rs_data rs
    ON rs.id = i.emvrsdata
    LEFT JOIN najme.IFX_CELL_CHARGE_DATA cell1
    ON cell1.id = i.charge
    LEFT JOIN najme.IFX_CELL_CHARGE_DATA_CHARGES cell
    ON cell.IFX_DATA = cell1.id
    LEFT JOIN najme.ifx_network_trn_info n
    ON i.nettrninfo = n.id
    LEFT JOIN najme.mtn_charge charge
    ON charge.cardserialno = cell.charge
    LEFT JOIN najme.trx_transaxion t
    ON i.trx = t.id
    LEFT JOIN najme.trx_flg_clearing sc
    ON sc.id                 = t.src_clr_flg
    WHERE i.ifx_type        IN (120, 281)
    AND i.trntype            = 19
    AND i.request            = 0
    AND i.direction          = 1
    AND rs.rscode            = '00'
    AND sc.clr_state        IN (1, 2)
    AND charge.cardserialno IS NOT NULL
    AND i.dummycol          IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
```

but when I run the view I have this Error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "COMPANY": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   that company is a field in mtn_charge table.
>   do you Know What should I do for this?

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: In your second view, you are selecting a column `company` from subquery which you haven't selected inside the subquery

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, The problem was solved.

Comment: You can significantly simplify your query. To get a 17 digit string, left padded with 0s if needed, you can simply use `to_char(x, 'fm00000000000000000')` (17 zeros, and fm means don't leave a space as placeholder for the sign, plus or minus). Similarly for the other numbers that require a length of 12.